# I have tried a sample example of bot builder connection to LUIS through Node.js. I am not able to connect to the LUIS

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I have tried to connect the bot to the LUIS engine through the URL,

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Create bot and bind to console
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

// Create LUIS recognizer that points at our model and add it as the root '/' dialog for our Cortana Bot.
var model = 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?id=c413b2ef-382c-45bd-8ff0-f76d60e2a821&subscription-key=[REMOVED SUBSCRIPTION KEY]&q=';
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', dialog);

// Add intent handlers
dialog.matches('builtin.intent.alarm.set_alarm', builder.DialogAction.send('Creating Alarm'));
dialog.matches('builtin.intent.alarm.delete_alarm', builder.DialogAction.send('Deleting Alarm'));
dialog.onDefault(builder.DialogAction.send("I'm sorry I didn't understand. I can only create & delete alarms."));
```

I am getting an error like

D:\SID\Bot_Frame\LUIS_BOT1>node app.js
i want to create alarm

```
default_error
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.projectoxford.ai:443
 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
 at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.on lookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
```

Comment: getadrrinfo EAI_AGAIN sounds like timeout or other problem with DNS lookup.  verify that your networking works and also do another simple network test with very short Node.js program like fetching a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be a transient error, so first try to run the app again. If the error persists, check your network settings. If you are using a proxy; make sure that [node and npm are well configured](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy).

From http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

> EAI_AGAIN actually means a temporary failure in name resolution or simply the name server returned a temporary failure indication
>
> EAI_AGAIN is actually a DNS lookup timed out error means it is either
>   a network connectivity error or some proxy related error. Try
>   resolving your proxy settings and check you have a decent internet
>   connection or not.

You can also try to run the [LUIS Node.js sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) but I don't think there is an error in your code and also the error message that you are getting is not around your code.